# Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, plugins, wildfly

I am working on a maven multi-module project Java EE 7 having the following folder structure.

```
+---parent-module
    +---module-domain
    +---module-service
    +---module-web
```

I want to configure the Wildfly maven plugin to deploy/undeploy aps to `Wildfly app server 8.0.0` and this is the pom.xml ( in the parent module's pom):

```
    <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                        <port>9990</port>
                        <username>admin</username>
                        <password>admin</password>
                        <!-- <jbossHome>C:/tools/wildfly-8.0.0.Final</jbossHome> -->
                    </configuration>
</plugin>

this is the log :

Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project .....Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to http-remoting://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out
```

====>Any clue please?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make any changes to the management port binding?

Comment: <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>

Comment: What's the port? The property should be `jboss.management.http.port`.

Comment: <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}

Comment: If that's the case the only reason it wouldn't connect is 1) It's not running, 2) The user admin has not been created. Since you're binding to localhost you could try commenting out the username and password.

Comment: I tried to comment the password and username but it's still same error. 1/when  I just execute mvn wildfly: start the server starts but I couldn't access the admin interface and I am asked to add a user admin (though I've already added a user) 2/ when I run mvn wildfly: deploy I see the error above.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the WildFly server is not running. Did you start it manually, or do you also use `wildfly:start` in your POM?

Comment: 1/I used the standalone script to start WildFly server and I've added a management user called "admin" to be able to acess the admin interface and everything is ok. 2/when I start the wildfly server using wildfly maven plugin mvn wildfly:start, the server is running but I have this message""Your WildFly Application Server is running. However you have not yet added any users to be able to access the admin console."" 3/ When i run mvn wildfly:deploy I have the error stated above.

Comment: The wildfly server is not running OR you did not specify the port or ip host correctly.

Answer (score 1):

With the information provided in the comments I think you're misunderstanding the goals a bit. The wildfly-maven-plugin is really used to fully manage a container. When you execute `mvn wildfly:start` the server process that was created is shutdown when maven exits. This is likely why you can't connect as there is no server running.

Not part of the answer, but feel free to file an [issue](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/issues) indicating you'd like to have the `start` goal not exit after maven exits. I'm likely not opposed to adding a boolean property which can be set to true that will leave the process running.

Comment: if I correctly understood your answer when I start the server ahead by using the standalone script and then run mvn wildfly:deploy the server process won't shutdown?  it would be really helpfu if you could explain further

Comment: Yes. Starting the server with the `standalone.(sh|bat)` the `wildfly:deploy` goal will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

There could be some dependency problems. Try to deploy your app manually via admin console, to see if some problems exist during deploy.

[image]

In my case I left some libraries as provided.